# Using grep to remove text after the first, or second, occurrence of a four digit string. Issue with hyphenated text

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to use grep and sed to format text and need help with my grep statement to include hyphens and preceding text in the output.

Example strings:

```
Merry.Ex-Mas.2014.1080p.Text.x265-JOHN
30.Rock.A.One-Time.Special.2020.1080p.Text.x265-JOHN
Creature.from.the.Black.Lagoon.REMASTERED.1954.1080p.BluRay.x265-JOHN
1984.1984.1080p.Text.x265-JOHN
```

The desired output would be:

```
Merry Ex-Mas 2014
30 Rock A One-Time Special 2020
Creature from the Black Lagoon 1954
1984 1984
```

Thanks to [@grzegorz-pudłowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12060936/grzegorz-pud%C5%82owski) I have this line of code. (but for some reason hyphens and everything in front of the hyphen is being removed)

```
`grep -E -o '(\\w*[\\.]?)*(19|20)[0-9]{2}'`
```

(the extra escapes are needed in AppleScript)

Those grep commands result in:

```
Mas.2014
Time.Special.2020
Creature.from.the.Black.Lagoon.1954
1984.1984
```

I then pipe to sed to replace periods with spaces:

```
 | sed 's/\\. */ /g'"
```

**The original answer from @grzegorz-pudłowski that was removed from stackoverflow:**

Better than sed should be grep in this situation. I gues you have bunch of files and you want to rename them or what not. So I would use something like this:

```
echo "Title.Text.2012.1080p.text.text" | grep -E -o "(\w*[\.]?)*(19|20)[0-9]{2}"
```

So... `-E` is "regex extended" flag. You can use `egrep` instead. Next flag is `-o` and it makes grep print only matched expression (as you want to throw away rest of this string).

Regexp is simple:

- `(\w*[\.]?)*` match zero or more groups of zero or more alphanumeric
  characters with zero or one dot at the end.
- `(19|20)` match 19 or 20 as you want to match a year (assuming years
  1900-2099 so change this part if you want wider range)
- `[0-9]{2}` match two digits from 0 to 9

After that you can pipe result to `mv` or what not. If you `grep` file however then just use:

```
grep -E -o "(\w*[\.]?)*(19|20)[0-9]{2}" filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using `sed` substitution:

```
sed -E 's/(.*(19|20)[0-9]{2}).*/\1/; s/\./ /g' file
```

```
Merry Ex-Mas 2014
30 Rock A One-Time Special 2020
1984 1984
```

**Details:**

- `(.*(19|20)[0-9]{2})`: Match longest string till we get a year string and capture in group #1
- `.*`: Match remaining part till end
- `\1`: Put 1st capture group back
- `s/\./ /g`: replace each dot with spacec

Comment: May be some copy/paste issue that you're getting `\r` pasted. Please try this on shell first. I can provide an online demo if you need.

Comment: In `gsub` function I used `" "` (double quotes) but you have `' '`  which is not even ASCII single quote

Comment: @John: Can you show your Appescript in question then may be I can suggest you something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219356/discussion-between-john-and-anubhava).

Comment: for reference in Apple Script the line is `"sed -E 's/(.*(19|20)[0-9]{2}).*/\\1/; s/\\./ /g'"`

Comment: Full Apple Script line is `set movie_titles to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (the clipboard as text) & "  | sed -E 's/(.*(19|20)[0-9]{2}).*/\\1/; s/\\./ /g'")`

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT2:*** In case OP wants to stick with his original solution with additional steps then try following.

```
grep -E -o "(\w+\.){1,}.*(19|20)[0-9]{2}" Input_file | sed 's/\./ /g'
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment adding more generic solution.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+\..*/){
  val=substr($0,1,RSTART+4)
  gsub(/\./," ",val)
  print val
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+p\.Text\..*Text//;s/\./ /g' Input_file
```

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="."
}
match($0,/\.[0-9]+p\.Text\..*Text/){
  $1=$1
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219352/discussion-between-john-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` expression using BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) can be written as:

```
sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/\w\w*p\s.*$//' file
```

Where the first substitution globally replaces each `'.'` with a space and then the second deletes from the word ending in `'p'` to the end of line. `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so you can tighten the matching criteria by adjusting the match of characters before `'p'` if needed.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/\w\w*p\s.*$//' file
Merry Ex-Mas 2014
30 Rock A One-Time Special 2020
1984 1984
```

---

**Per-Edits To Include Additional Strings**

Including additional strings such as:

- `"WALL-E.2008.1080p.BluRay.x265-JOHN"`, and
- `"WALL-E.2008.REMASTERED.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG"`

To use BRE you would need:

```
sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/^[0-9][0-9]*[ ]\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1 \1/;s/[ ]\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*$/ \1/' file
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
Merry.Ex-Mas.2014.1080p.Text.x265.Text
30.Rock.A.One-Time.Special.2020.1080p.Text.x265.Text
1984.1984.1080p.Text.x265.Text
WALL-E.2008.1080p.BluRay.x265-JOHN
WALL-E.2008.REMASTERED.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/^[0-9][0-9]*[ ]\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1 \1/;s/[ ]\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*$/ \1/' file
Merry Ex-Mas 2014
30 Rock A One-Time Special 2020
1984 1984
WALL-E 2008
WALL-E 2008
```

Comment: The orginal text that needs to be edited is in this format: WALL-E.2008.1080p.BluRay.x265-JOHN. Your sed doesn't seem to remove everything from and including 1080p.

Comment: @John due you expect something other than `"WALL-E 2008"` in that case?

Comment: $ echo "WALL-E.2008.1080p.BluRay.x265-JOHN" | sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/\w\w*p\s.*$//' returns WALL-E 2008 1080p BluRay x265-JOHN

Comment: I ask because you treat `"Ex-Mas"` as a single word in your example.

Comment: @John - what OS are you using? Does your `sed` not support `\w`? In that case, use `sed 's/[.]/ /g;s/[0-9][0-9]*p[ \t].*$//'`

Comment: Okay, so you would still want `"WALL-E.2008"` only and delete from `"REMASTERED"` on?

Comment: I accepted an answer above which seems to work well. Thanks David.

Comment: I added an example. No worries. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/\.1080p\..*//g;s/\./ /g' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/gQ9z12)

**Details**

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `s/\.1080p\..*//g` - removes the `.1080.` and all text to the end of string
- `s/\./ /g` - replaces dots with spaces.

Test:

```
#!/bin/bash
s='Merry.Ex-Mas.2014.1080p.
30.Rock.A.One-Time.Special.2020.1080p.
1984.1984.1080p.'
sed -E 's/\.1080p\..*//g;s/\./ /g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Merry Ex-Mas 2014
30 Rock A One-Time Special 2020
1984 1984
```

Comment: Thanks! but I edited the original question to clarify. There is text that comes after the second occurrence of numerals and it also needs to be removed. Your sed argument works for me in Terminal except for that.

Comment: Essentially everything after the year needs to be removed starting from '.1080p' and including any space at the end.

Comment: this is so close can you help with arguments to remove the text from '.1080p' to the end? The original grep statement worked well for this but had issues with it removing hyphens and the text before hyphens.

Comment: @John All you needed is a `.*` after `\.`. Also, if `1080p` is the only resolution you can have in the strings, just use `1080p`  instead of `[0-9]+p`. I updated the answer.